# Diference between Numberlong(x) and Numberlong("x")

Tags: mongodb

I stored some XML data in MongoDB databse. Some of the data is stored as `Numberlong(1234)` and some other as `Numberlong("12353")`. Example:

```
"nodes_id" : [
    NumberLong(13879272),
    NumberLong(252524625),
    NumberLong(252524611),
    NumberLong(252524630),
    NumberLong(149809404),
    NumberLong(605181143),
    NumberLong("3068489546"),
    NumberLong("3059300418"),
    NumberLong(253351454),
    NumberLong(253351438),
    NumberLong(253348623),
    NumberLong(253351472)
]
```

Is there any difference between the two types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NumberLong(253351454)` only works for numbers that are small enough that they don't need to be ... well, long: The shell must represent them in JS somehow, so it can only represent numbers that

For larger numbers, a textual representation is required because there's no large enough data type available, hence `NumberLong("3059300418")` with `3059300418 > 253351454`.

In other words, no, *there's no difference*. It's just a limitation of the shell, or more generally speaking, of JS and floating point numbers.

Caveat: Don't try to invoke the constructor with a too large number, i.e. don't try `db.foo.insert({"t" : NumberLong(1234657890132456789)});` Since that number is way too large for a double, it will cause roundoff errors. Above number would be converted to `NumberLong("1234657890132456704")`, which is wrong, obviously.

Comment: nice, it is good  to know about this mongo shell limitation +1

Comment: @Disposer `NumberDecimal` can be used for numbers longer than the `NumberLong`.