# Why NumberLong(9007199254740993) matches NumberLong(9007199254740992) in MongoDB from mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, long-integer

[image]

This situation happens when the given number is big enough (greater than 9007199254740992), along with more tests, I even found many adjacent numbers could match a single number.

Not only `NumberLong(9007199254740996)` would match `NumberLong("9007199254740996")`, but also `NumberLong(9007199254740995)` and `NumberLong(9007199254740997)`.

When I want to act upon a record using its number, I could actually use three different adjacent numbers to get back the same record.

[image]

Comment: `NumberDecimal` can be used for numbers longer than the `NumberLong`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054522/diference-between-numberlongx-and-numberlongx) makes sense, I quote the most relevant part below：

> Caveat: Don't try to invoke the constructor with a too large number, i.e. don't try `db.foo.insert({"t" : NumberLong(1234657890132456789)})`; Since that number is way too large for a double, it will cause roundoff errors. Above number would be converted to `NumberLong("1234657890132456704")`, which is wrong, obviously.

Here are some supplements to make things more clear：

Firstly, Mongo shell is a JavaScript shell. And JS does not distinguish between integer and floating-point values. All numbers in JS are represented as floating point values. This means mongo shell uses 64 bit floating point number by default. If shell sees `"9007199254740995"`, it will treat this as a string and convert it to `long long`. But when we omit the double quotes, mongo shell will see unquoted `9007199254740995` and treat it as a floating-point number.

Secondly, JS uses the 64 bit floating-point format defined in IEEE 754 standard to represent numbers, the maximum it can represent is:

[image]

, and the minimum is:

[image]

**There are an infinite number of real numbers, but only a limited number of real numbers can be accurately represented in the JS floating point format. This means that when you deal with real numbers in JS, the representation of the numbers will usually be an approximation of the actual numbers.**

This brings the so-called rounding error issue. Because integers are also represented in binary floating-point format, the reason for the loss of trailing digits precision is actually the same as that of decimals.

The JS number format allows you to accurately represent all integers between

[image]

and

[image]

Here, since the numbers are bigger than 9007199254740992, the rounding error certainly occurs. The binary representation of `NumberLong(9007199254740995)`, `NumberLong(9007199254740996)` and `NumberLong(9007199254740997)` are the same. So when we query with these three numbers in this way, we are practically asking for the same thing. As a result,  we will get back the same record.

I think understanding that this problem is not specific to JS is important: it affects any programming language that uses binary floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the NumberLong constructor.

The correct usage is to give it a string argument, as stated in the [relevant documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/).

```
NumberLong("2090845886852")
```